os.environ.get() returns None in Flask app
Problem
Flask app returns None when an environmental variable os.environ.get() is rendered in template mapboxgl.accessToken = {{ mapbox_access_token }}.
Workfiles
Environmental variable is saved in ~/.bashrc: export MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN='XXXXXXXX'
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    access_token = os.environ.get('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN')
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    return render_template('index.html', mapbox_access_token=access_token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

The error appears to be in this line access_token = os.environ.get('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'), as I tried replacing with access_token = XXXXXXXX which renders fine. However, obviously I want to avoid hard-coding sensitive information to the file.

There's a very simple explanation to this: MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN is not in your environment.

Does "access_token" show any data when it's initialized? If you do "print(access_token)" after it is initialized, it will show data?

Is "~/.bashrc:" the same as an .env file? Usually, in Flask, I see people put their environment variables in an .env file.

@GetOverHere ~/.bashrc is a dotfile for the bash shell. Every time the bash shell is started, the contents of ~/.bashrc are run. In this, case the MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN should be set -but only if the OP was running the script in the bash shell. If the OP was running in a shell other than bash (zsh, fish, etc.), that would explain why MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN is not set. @alexalexalex, I would suggest you to post the line where you set the MAPBOX_ACESS_TOKEN variable.

Exactly how are you running your flask program? .bashrc only gets run when starting an interactive shell and not when starting a non-interactive shell so it would not be run if you are running your server as a service.

maybe before you run flask use command env in shell to see what variables are in system. You may also use env | sort to sort them - and it will be simpler to search MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN. Or you can use env | grep TOKEN to see all variables with word TOKEN
